# R - Multiplying Characters, Dates, Numbers, etc

Tags: r

Say I have a DF with a column of unique dates.

I also have a DF with columns (duplicates occur):

```
V1 - "Standard", "Video", "Audio"
V2 - "Desktop", "Mobile", "Tablet", "Cross Device"
```

I am beginner but I tried setting values as numeric and vectors as well as use lapply and I haven't gotten it to work, did a quick search and couldn't find any helpful examples; apologies if this is too straightforward to be asked!

How would multiply the non-numeric observations against each other to get this result (lets say I only have one observation for date, 1/1/2015):

```
Date      V1         V2
1/1/2015  Standard   Desktop
1/1/2015  Standard   Mobile
1/1/2015  Standard   Tablet
1/1/2015  Standard   Cross Device
1/1/2015  Video      Desktop
1/1/2015  Video      Mobile
1/1/2015  Video      Tablet
1/1/2015  Video      Cross Device
```

ETC....

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but maybe `?expand.grid`

Comment: @Frank right on brother, this is exactly what I need.  My only issue is that it does it for duplicate values; so say I have a list with 300 "Standard" observations, and a list of ten dates, I should only get those ten dates defined as "Standard", instead I get those 10 dates defined as "Standard" but multiplied by 300 for a total of 3000 rows!

Solved it by incorporating unique()

Comment: `do.call(expand.grid, lapply(DF[my_colnames], unique))` should work. Or you could use `library(data.table); CJ(col1, col2, ...., unique=TRUE)`